# Need help finding the right video production software

Tags: video-editor, software-recommendation

I have the following situation:
- I need to create a movie in the format .mov or .mp4 on Windows 8.
- As sources I have already 10 .mov files in a format 1600x1200 on Windows8. (originals)
- I need to speed up some parts of my video up to 30 from the original.
- I need to export the constructed video again as 1600 x 1200 in .mov or .mp4 with the same quality as the originals.

I tried to do this already with my tools I already have, but I did not succeed:
My Software:
- Microsoft movie maker
- Handbrake
- Movie Studio Platinum 13.0
- Windows8

I like the simple MovieMaker, but it cannot handle/produce 1600*1200.
Also Movie Studio Platinum 13.0 can't produce 1600*1200 and I am not able to speed up the video more then 4x.

Any hints ?

**UPDATE**

My Speeduf problem is solved, but I am still searching for a performant reliable software to create videos in the format 1600*1200.
I have Movie Studio Platinum 13.0 which is unusable. It produces black screens in some parts of the video and it lags. I have a high performant computer with 24GB of ram.

Can someone suggest any software ?

Comment: Is it 1600x1200 or 1200x1600?

Comment: Its landscape 1600 width and 1200 heigth

Comment: Do you mean speed it up 30x, or speed it up to 30 fps? What is the original frame rate?

Comment: Does Blackmagic's DaVinci Resolve support 1600 x 1200 ?

Comment: Resolve requires Windows 10.  Windows 8 is a strange and unfortunate choice, but, whatever.

Comment: @audionuma Yeah. You can pick any resolution you'd like. (It needs to be dividable by two.)

Comment: @TimothyLukasH.it doesn't even have to be divisible by 2.  At least not in Studio.  I can't imagine that they limited it in that way in the free version since it's basically full featured aside from a few high end modules.

Answer (score 2):

You could use Davinci Resolve. The free version can do all the things you want.
It's a professional software tho, so you'll maybe need to read into it.
But you can allways ask here, we can guide you further if you're stuck.

Comment: I'd second Resolve.  Especially with the last couple versions it has become a true professional NLE and the free version is very full functional with the studio version being only a one time $300 fee which includes functionality that would typically cost thousands of dollars.  It does mean a steeper learning curve, but it's a curve that will serve you well if you decide to branch to any other professional NLEs since pro NLEs in general work pretty similar.

Comment: The one gotcha here is that they'll have to use Resolve 12 since they aren't on Windows 10.  12 did have NLE functions, but it was not nearly as refined as it is in 14 or 15.

Answer (score 1):

Two free and open-source video editors are, [Kdenlive](https://kdenlive.org/) and [OpenShot](https://www.openshot.org/). They were originally only on Linux but recently got betas for Windows. You will need to install a couple of libraries for the software to run but one should work for you.

Answer (score 0):

Blender VSE is an option that can do those things you need. It uses ffmpeg to do its renders. The main drawback is it renders very slowly, forcing things to a single cpu core, as well it lacks certain things you might want such as sharpeners and support for specific formats like textfiles and gif. Or if you were making 2d text for example it has only basic single font functionality as a preset.

However it offers, in conjunction with the 3d viewport and python scripting, ways to address many of these issues. For the most part it's an open toolbox, it can go as far as you program it to.

Comment: Resolve can handle custom resolution just fine.  The rest of the issues have been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/88486/discussion-on-answer-by-kite-need-help-finding-the-right-video-production-softwa).